# Multithreading, lambdas and local variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, lambda, task-parallel-library

My question is, in the below code, can I be sure that the instance methods will be accessing the variables I think they will, or can they be changed by another thread while I'm still working? Do closures have anything to do with this, i.e. will I be working on a local copy of the `IEnumerable<T>` so enumeration is safe?

To paraphrase my question, do I need any locks if I'm never writing to shared variables?

```
public class CustomerClass
{
    private Config cfg = (Config)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Customer");

    public void Run()
    {
        var serviceGroups = this.cfg.ServiceDeskGroups.Select(n => n.Group).ToList();

        var groupedData = DataReader.GetSourceData().AsEnumerable().GroupBy(n => n.Field<int>("ID"));
        Parallel.ForEach<IGrouping<int, DataRow>, CustomerDataContext>(
            groupedData,
            () => new CustomerDataContext(),
            (g, _, ctx) =>
            {
                var inter = this.FindOrCreateInteraction(ctx, g.Key);

                inter.ID = g.Key;
                inter.Title = g.First().Field<string>("Title");

                this.CalculateSomeProperty(ref inter, serviceGroups);

                return ctx;
            },
            ctx => ctx.SubmitAllChanges());
    }

    private Interaction FindOrCreateInteraction(CustomerDataContext ctx, int ID)
    {
        var inter = ctx.Interactions.Where(n => n.Id = ID).SingleOrDefault();

        if (inter == null)
        {
            inter = new Interaction();
            ctx.InsertOnSubmit(inter);
        }

        return inter;
    }

    private void CalculateSomeProperty(ref Interaction inter, IEnumerable<string> serviceDeskGroups)
    {
        // Reads from the List<T> class instance variable. Changes the state of the ref'd object.
        if (serviceGroups.Contains(inter.Group))
        {
            inter.Ours = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the implementation of CustomerDataContext? This would seem to be the only place where a data race could currently be occuring.

Comment: CustomerDataContext is a standard Entity Framework DataContext and is actually thread-local, so no data races there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer and in the process, also the question.

The real question was whether local "variables", that turn out to be actually objects, can be trusted for concurrent access. The answer is no, if they happen to have internal state that is not handled in a thread-safe manner, all bets are off. The closure doesn't help, it just captures a reference to said object.

In my specific case - concurrent reads from `IEnumerable<T>` and no writes to it, it *is* actually thread safe, because each call to `foreach`, `Contains()`, `Where()`, etc. gets a fresh new `IEnumerator`, which is only visible from the thread that requested it. Any other objects, however, must also be checked, one by one.

So, hooray, no locks or synchronized collections for me :)

Thanks to @ebb and @Dave, although you didn't answer the question directly, you pointed me in the right direction.

---

If you're interested in the results, this is a run on my home PC (a quad-core) with `Thread.SpinWait` to simulate the processing time of a row. The real app had an improvement of almost 2X (01:03 vs 00:34) on a dual-core hyper-threaded machine with SQL Server on the local network.

[image: Singlethreaded]
Single-threaded, using `foreach`. I don't know why, but there is a pretty high number of cross-core context switches.

[image: Multithreaded]
Using `Parallel.ForEach`, lock-free with thread-locals where needed.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, from what I can tell, your instance methods are not using any member variables. That makes them stateless and therefore threadsafe. However, in that same case, you'd be better off marking them "static" for code clarity and a slight performance benefit.

If those instance methods were using a member variable, then they'd only be as threadsafe as that variable (for example, if you used a simple list, it would not be threadsafe and you may see weird behavior). Long story short, member variables are the enemy of easy thread safety.

Here's my refactor (disclaimer, not tested). If you want to provide data that's passed in, you'll stay saner if you pass them as parameters and don't keep them as member variables :

UPDATE: You asked for a way to reference your read only list, so I've added that and removed the static tags (so that the instance variable can be shared).

```
public class CustomerClass
{

private List<string> someReadOnlyList;

    public CustomerClass(){
      List<string> tempList  = new List<string>() { "string1", "string2" };
      someReadOnlyList = ArrayList.Synchronized(tempList);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var groupedData = DataReader.GetSourceData().AsEnumerable().GroupBy(n => n.Field<int>("ID"));

        Parallel.ForEach<IGrouping<int, DataRow>, CustomerDataContext>(
            groupedData,
            () => new CustomerDataContext(),
            (g, _, ctx) =>
            {
                var inter = FindOrCreateInteraction(ctx, g.Key);

                inter.ID = g.Key;
                inter.Title = g.First().Field<string>("Title");

                CalculateSomeProperty(ref inter);

                return ctx;
            },
            ctx => ctx.SubmitAllChanges());
    }

    private Interaction FindOrCreateInteraction(CustomerDataContext ctx, int ID)
    {
        var query = ctx.Interactions.Where(n => n.Id = ID);

        if (query.Any())
        {
            return query.Single();
        }
        else
        {
            var inter = new Interaction();
            ctx.InsertOnSubmit(inter);
            return inter;
        }
    }

    private void CalculateSomeProperty(ref Interaction inter)
    {
        Console.Writeline(someReadOnlyList[0]);
        //do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) However, if I'm not writing to that list but only reading from it? The second method, `CalculateSomeProperty()` looks some stuff up from this `List<T>`, however never adding or removing from it. It's easier to have it visible from the whole class, because other methods need it.

Comment: @VladislavZorov, `ReadOnlyCollection` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx

Comment: So it seems even reading the `List<T>` (or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`) is not a thread-safe operation. However I can't understand the sentence "Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe"? Why?

Comment: You can use ArrayList.Synchronized(IList) to return a threadsafe wrapped version of your list. I'm going to edit my answer to show this.                                              http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx

Comment: "ctx.InsertOnSubmit(inter)" in FindOrCreateInteraction would be changing the internal state of the context and you would need to check that InsertOnSubmit is thread-safe (I have tried finding out... I'm not sure that it is but can't be sure).

If it's not then you would want to synchronize access to the ctx variable in that method

Comment: The context is not shared. It is passed and initialized as a thread-local variable.